# How do I add CSS files only to the front page?

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to add a CSS file to the front page. I have seen [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets); I just need to know the HOOK machine name for the front page.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables) {
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'CSSPATH';
}
```

What name should I use for the preprocess function, in order to make Drupal calls it only for the front page?

Comment: Have updated the answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please follow as I have described, It must work. I have tested in my trial site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find exactly what you want under the topic **Adding Libraries to Specific Pages** at this tutorial [Drupal 8 Theming Fundamentals, Part 1](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-8-theming-fundamentals-part-1)

To give you a real example, I am going to explain with the Bartik theme, so you can change easily.

I have created a css file `cssfile.css` under the path `css/cssfile.css`. Now this CSS file I want to use on only front page.

- **Step 1: Add the library to the theme:** Add the following code in the `bartik.libraries.yml`

  ```
  css-filling: 
    css:
      theme:
        css/cssfile.css: {}
  ```

  *Note: Here I have given the name `css-filling` to this library but you can give any other name. We will use this name in path*
- **Step 2:** Setting the code in `bartik.theme` so above perticular library(ultimately css) will only be added to front-page,

  ```
  function bartik_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if ($variables['is_front']) {
      $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'bartik/css-filling';
    }
  }
  ```

  *Note: Now in the above code the important thing is path, `bartik` part comes form the `themename` and `css-filling` comes from the step-1.*

This code I have tested in my test site and it is working on front-page only.

Comment: You can find more tutorial at that article, Just that link is not opening and that entire site at this point, Looks like that site is under-maintenance, but I am linking raw link- https://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-8-theming-fundamentals-part-1, so in future you can refer.

Answer (score 8):

You can attach libraries in templates, for example `html.html.twig` is an ideal place to attach libraries conditional on the path. You can either use template suggestions, e.g. `html--front.html.twig` or a twig expression.

The other answers revolve around preprocess, which is fine, however preprocess is an abstraction and makes theming development more opaque, i.e. it buries important information in a PHP function, rather than being obvious and clear in the template.

I'm not saying preprocess is bad, only that it depends largely on how you want to work and how opaque/abstract you want to theme.

To attach a library only for the front page in `html.html.twig` we can use the `not` operator and the `root_path` variable as a condition:

```
{{ not root_path ? attach_library('my_theme/my_library') }}
```

If you create the template suggestion `html--front.html.twig` you can attach the library unconditionally:

```
{{ attach_library('my_theme/my_library') }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have created the css you want as a library in `libraries.yml` first. Then you need to use `hook_preprocess_page()` like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for page templates.
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Add page preprocess functions here.
  if ($variables['is_front'] == TRUE) {
    // Attach your css 
    // - replace "theme_name" with the name of your theme
    // - replace "library_name" with the name of what you called 
    //   this particular css library in libraries.yml
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'theme_name/library_name'
  }
}
```

You might be better creating a `page--front.html.twig` file and attaching it there instead via your `libraries.yml` file. This is the preferred approach in Drupal 8.

Comment: Make sure you change `THEMENAME` to the name of your theme. You will also need to give a path to the css file, something like `$variables['#attached']['library'][] = $variables['directory']' . 'css/front.css'; }`

Comment: @Chris Happy $variables['#attached']['library'][] is to attach a library, as defined in themeName.libraries.yml, not the path to a file. E.g. $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'theme_name/library_name';

Comment: I've updated my answer with @JeffBurnz's comment. My _path_to_css_ approach was D7.