# Load a CSS file only for anonymous users visiting the front page

Tags: 8, theming

I want to load a CSS file only for the front page, and only for users who didn't log in. Both conditions should be met; in the other cases, the CSS file should not be added to the page.

How do I achieve this in a preprocess function?

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting this. It seems like a clear question as to what the user is looking for. If someone downvotes, they should include a comment to help the poster improve their post, otherwise that downvote isn't helpful at all.

Comment: @Jaypan – The request is valid, of course. But since the question is asking for custom code it's lacking info on previous attempts/code to fix.

Comment: That's a good comment for the OP for future reference.

Comment: I think this question is a "Google it for me" one. By a quick search on google or a proper reading of drupal.org theme basics documentation, you can get an answer for it.

Comment: Not everyone using Drupal is a programmer.

Comment: @Jaypan voting isn’t designed for the user posting the question, there are volumes of literature in the help center, and an entire site (meta) to cover that. Voting is quality signalling; it’s for the _rest_ of the community. Due to the unfortunate realities of human nature, explaining votes is actually discouraged. It inevitably leads to aggressive behaviour: insults, revenge downvoting, cyber stalking, death threats - I’ve seen and received them all, and my honest advice to anyone using Stack sites is just vote and leave it

Comment: Those are also problems, but I don't think they are justification for a downvote without an explanation. I was on a different Stack Exchange site, for Japanese language, and even though I've been studying Japanese 20 years, am fluent, and have a lot of help to give others, I left because of downvotes without explanation. They serve no positive purpose when left without an explanation, and only serve to discourage. This can lead to situations like mine, where someone who can benefit the community doesn't want to. It's a major problem with the stack exchange communities in my opinion.

Comment: I agree if you look at it from the point of view of one person, the OP, but that’s not what we do - we look at it from the point of the view of the community, and the intention of the site in the first place. Votes, in either direction, very much do serve     a positive purpose. The comments are incidental, and as I mentioned, discouraged for what history shows us are good reasons. That’s not to say I want to encourage you to leave or anything. I definitely don’t :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using a preprocess function can also solve this, here is the template file approach.

Copy template file page.html.twig and rename the copy to page--front.html.twig

Assuming you have already [defined a library](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module) for your .css file.

In page--front.html.twig add

```
{% if not logged_in %}
    {{ attach_library('theme_name/library-name') }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two steps to this:

1. Creating a library that references the CSS file
2. Attaching that library to the front page

Let's assume your module is named `example`, and the css file is 'example/css/example_front_page.css`. First, the libraries file needs to be created, declaring the CSS file.

example.libraries.yml:

```
front_page:
  css:
    theme:
      css/example_front_page.css: {}
```

Read more: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module

Next, you can implement hook_page_attachments to attach the library:

```
function example_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {

  // Check if on front page.
  if ( \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage() && \Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
    // This is the front page, so the library is attached.
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'example/front_page';
  }
}
```

Comment: OP wants to include the lib only for anonymous users. What you describe has already been answered in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/212011/15055 and https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/229079/15055.

Comment: Fair enough, then it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Well, there was no question yet on how to include a lib for a given role.